# Swift 3 Alamofire Swifty json parsing issue

Tags: json, parsing, swift3, alamofire

I have a problem with parsing json. I've been searching for a while how to solve this but no success.

My json output looks like this:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "type": "schedules",
        "id": "1",
        "attributes": {
            "date": "2016-12-24"
        },
        "relationships": {
            "user": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "users",
                    "id": "8"
                }
            },
            "statuses": {
                "data": [{
                    "type": "statuses",
                    "id": "2"
                }]
            },
            "events": {
                "data": [{
                    "type": "events",
                    "id": "7"
                }]
            }
        }
    }, {
        "type": "schedules",
        "id": "2",
        "attributes": {
            "date": "2016-12-04"
        },
        "relationships": {
            "user": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "users",
                    "id": "8"
                }
            },
            "statuses": {
                "data": [{
                    "type": "statuses",
                    "id": "12"
                }, {
                    "type": "statuses",
                    "id": "16"
                }, {
                    "type": "statuses",
                    "id": "17"
                }]
            },
            "events": {
                "data": [{
                    "type": "events",
                    "id": "16"
                }, {
                    "type": "events",
                    "id": "17"
                }, {
                    "type": "events",
                    "id": "1"
                }]
            }
        }
    }, {
        "type": "schedules",
        "id": "3",
        "attributes": {
            "date": "2002-12-03"
        },
        "relationships": {
            "user": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "users",
                    "id": "7"
                }
            },
            "statuses": {
                "data": [{
                    "type": "statuses",
                    "id": "3"
                }, {
                    "type": "statuses",
                    "id": "11"
                }]
            },
            "events": {
                "data": [{
                    "type": "events",
                    "id": "4"
                }, {
                    "type": "events",
                    "id": "19"
                }]
            }
        }
    }],
    "included": [

        {
            "type": "events",
            "id": "6",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "streamline leading-edge portals",
                "event_type": "3",
                "start_time": "22:20:04",
                "end_time": "20:19:22"
            }
        }, {
            "type": "events",
            "id": "11",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "maximize dynamic niches",
                "event_type": "8",
                "start_time": "15:51:06",
                "end_time": "22:24:56"
            }
        }, {
            "type": "events",
            "id": "12",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "transition vertical methodologies",
                "event_type": "1",
                "start_time": "19:55:59",
                "end_time": "00:27:42"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My swift to obtain this looks like this:

```
func getSchedules<T: JSONObject>(_ success: @escaping ([T]) -> Void) {
        self.getAllScheduleData { (json) in

            var items: [T] = []

            if let jsonArray = json.array {
                for jsonItem in jsonArray {
                    items.append(T.fromJSONComplete(json: jsonItem) as! T)
                }
            }

            success(items)
        }
    }
```

self.getAllScheduleData does a API call using Alamofire

The problem here is, json.array is always empty. As I understand it should always be something like: json["items"].array.

However this json has no top layer to call. i.e. items.

My options now are to either get json["data"] or json["included"]. But i want to have them both to parse it to an object.

Not sure how to explain this better unfortunately
If you need more info, just ask.

I am using: Swift 3, Alamofire, SwiftyJSON

**edit:**
I have also considered to add a top layer to it after getting json from call. 
i.e. items{ data{}, included{}}
but did not manage to do it right

if I use the for in syntax as suggested by Emptyless, I probably have to change the signature of this method, right?

```
static func fromJSONComplete<T : Object>(json: JSON) -> T {

        let s = Schedule()

        if let id = json["data"]["id"].string {
            s.id = id
        }

        if let date = json["data"]["attributes"]["date"].string {
            s.date = date
        }

        if let type = json["data"]["type"].string {
            s.type = type
        }

        if let includedArray = json["included"].array {
            for userJson in includedArray {
                if userJson["type"].string == "users" {
                    let user : User = User.fromJSON(json: userJson)

                    s.users.append(user)
                }
            }

            for statusJson in includedArray {
                if statusJson["type"].string == "statuses" {
                    let status : Status = Status.fromJSON(json: statusJson)
                    s.statuses.append(status)
                }
            }

            for eventJson in includedArray {
                if eventJson["type"].string == "events" {
                    let event : Event = Event.fromJSON(json: eventJson)
                    s.events.append(event)
                }
            }
        }

        return s as! T
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Chris

Comment: have you tried the for in syntax? for (key, subJSON) in json { }. Then you can iterate over both keys "data" and "included" using json[key].

Comment: @Emptyless I have tried it but I think I don't fully understand how it is used. Could you give me a code example?

Answer (score 0):

The code example as requested:

```
for (key,subjson) in json {
    for i in 1 ..< json[key].count where subjson.array != nil {
        print("found json for key: \(key): \(json[key][i])")
    }
}
```

It checks the json object provided and iterates over the available top-keys. If the key contains an array of some object  it will also iterate over it.

An approach I mostly use to for example is to switch on the key and pass the json object as an initializer, but it can also be used to split up in functions.

e.g.

```
switch(key) {
case "included":
     // Do something
case "data":
    // Do Something
default:
    break
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Emptyless! It worked :D
I upvoted you but it does not register yet because of my low rep lol